# Select a Gurobi variable from a set of items

Tags: gurobi

I'm generating variables for my problem in the following format:

```
model.addVars(gurobi_vars, name='n', vtype=GRB.INTEGER, lb=n_lb, ub=n_ub)
```

However, instead of putting a lower bound and upper bound for the variable I want it to be added from a set of integers x={0, 1, 4, 16 , 64}. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling questions belong on or.stackexchange.com